# react-native-camera Cannot read property 'Constants' of undefined on android

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, react-native-camera

I'm aware of [this](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-video/issues/354) issue.
I have installed and configured the react-native-camera this way:

```
yarn add react-native-camera --save
react-native link react-native-camera
```

added these to **AndroidManifest.xml**:

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I'm using [this](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-camera/blob/master/docs/RNCamera.md) basic code:

```
 <RNCamera
          ref={ref => {
            this.camera = ref;
          }}
          style={styles.preview}
          type={RNCamera.Constants.Type.back}
          flashMode={RNCamera.Constants.FlashMode.on}
          androidCameraPermissionOptions={{
            title: 'Permission to use camera',
            message: 'We need your permission to use your camera',
            buttonPositive: 'Ok',
            buttonNegative: 'Cancel',
          }}
          androidRecordAudioPermissionOptions={{
            title: 'Permission to use audio recording',
            message: 'We need your permission to use your audio',
            buttonPositive: 'Ok',
            buttonNegative: 'Cancel',
          }}
          onGoogleVisionBarcodesDetected={({ barcodes }) => {
            console.log(barcodes);
          }}
        />
```

And get this error:

> ExceptionsManager.js:74 TypeError: TypeError: Cannot read property 'Constants' of undefined

Comment: Try linking it manually.

Comment: I've tried. No difference.

Answer (score 0):

Try these :

1. Check if react-native link worked or not by opening `MainApplication.java(app\src\main\java\com\YourAppName\MainApplication.java)` file and search for 'camera' if you found something related to camera, it means react-native link worked. If you didn't found 'camera' then you need to manually link.
2. Try uninstalling the app, close all the terminals where you have started packager i.e. `react-native start`. Then reinstall the app by running `react-native run-android` command.

Comment: I've checked all the native files. The needed modifications are there.

Comment: I followed these steps and it worked : 1. `yarn add react-native-camera` 2. `react-native link react-native-camera` 3. added this line `missingDimensionStrategy 'react-native-camera', 'general'` inside `android/app/build.gradle` file. Then run react-native run-android again.